# Что в коде не так?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1000;
    for (; a <= 0; ) {
        cout << a << " ";
        a = a - 2;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что в заголовке вопроса не так? Как постороннему понять задачу по такому "информативному" названию?

Comment: При создании проекта вы попросили компилятор использовать прекомпиляцию заголовочных файлов. По вашему коду, однако, видно, что вы не знаете, как MSVC работает прекомпиляция заголовочных файлов. Так может лучше ее просто отключить? Зачем вы ее вообще запросили?

Comment: @AnT Насколько я помню, она там автоматом устанавливается... :(

Comment: @Harry: Она по умолчанию устанавливается, да, но при этом в процессе создания проекта эта установка показывается пользователю с предложением изменить выбор. Понятно, конечно, что пользователь, который еще не в курсе, что это такое, предпочтет оставить установку по умолчанию...

Comment: Обычно и `int a = 1000` и `a = a - 2`  ставят "внутрь" скобок оператора `for`, оно будет и короче, и понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

должно идти первым, **до**

```
#include <iostream>
```

Это для компиляции. Что до смысла программы - то, может, вам так и надо - чтоб она просто ничего не делала, ограничившись

```
system ("pause");
```

Если же вы хотите иного - то, наверное,

```
for (; a <= 0; ) {
```

должно быть

```
for (; a >= 0; ) {
```

Но тут уж вам виднее...